# Need help, in displaying a value of javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

Check this code

```
function readvalue() {
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

var value = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\CurrentVersion");
write("<text class="
name ">");
write(value);
write("</text>");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SrikanthYadake/2E5rE/2/

I am unable to present the text in variable "value" inside the blue box.

Please help.

Comment: Which browser you are using? Active-x objects only work with IE.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

```
function readvalue() {
    var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

    var value = WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\CurrentVersion");
    document.write("<text class='name'>" + value+"</text>" );
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/FYA8Y/) updated

Comment: that works,but the blue box disappears.. it is has someting to do with css

Comment: There's no `<text>` element ;-)

Comment: You can use <div> instead of <text>

Comment: To even have access to be able to read keys from the registry seems like a **massive** security issue.

Comment: @NickR : any alternatives? I am preparing a windows gadget just to read a value from local registry..

Comment: @Sriyad Place the CSS properties of border in name CSS class

Comment: @ChiragVidani can u help me in my fiddle space?

Comment: @ChiragVidani nope that didnt help

Comment: @Sriyad Try to use jQuery html instead of document.write(). Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/chiragvidani/E9QLp/)

Comment: @ChiragVidani nice work. but should this go inside the script tag?

Comment: @Sriyad Yes the jquery is placed in script tag as we do with javascript

Comment: cool, im unable to get the registry value now! the box and the image came

Comment: @Sriyad you can mark it as answer now if your criteria is fulfilled

Comment: @ChiragVidani : i am unable to see registry value yet!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33276/discussion-between-sriyad-and-chirag-vidani)

Comment: @ChiragVidani : can you let me know with your jquery code as to how to print the variable value?

Comment: @Sriyad add to div's html. $('div').html(variable). Don't forget to place div in html

Answer (score 0):

check the below code:

```
write("<text class="
name ">");
write(value);
write("</text>");
```

It have some error. so replace with:

```
write("<text class='name'>");
write(value);
write("</text>");
```